# oracle collection not enough values

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, sql-types

I did following:

```
create or replace type my_row as object 
    (
     lname varchar2(30),
     fname varchar2(30),
     MI char(1),
     hohSSN char (9),
     hohname VARCHAR2(63),
     hohDob char(10),
     dob DATE
     ); 

create or replace type eiv.my_rec as table of eiv.my_row;
```

but then doing query like:

my_records my_rec

```
select '', '', '', '', '', '', sysdate bulk collect into my_records from dual;
```

gives error `ORA-00947: not enough values`

what can i be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

When populating SQL types with bulk collect we need to include the row (not the table) type.

```
select my_row ('', '', '', '', '', '', sysdate )
bulk collect into my_records 
from dual;
```

Comment: +1 I'm surprised you need to stipulate the record type in the select. This differs from the varray mechanism. @john, isn't this the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you man, i just wasted good part of the day trying to figure this out!
For record types this isn't necessary, but for object types as you wisely mentioned this is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

no FROM clause.

try `FROM DUAL`